# Is it correct and natural to say "I do BMX" meaning I engage in BMX cycling?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *I do BMX* meaning I engage in BMX cycling? For example:

> Person A: What sports do you do?
>
> Person B: Oh, I **do** BMX.

Comment: Strange that someone would ask what sports do you do instead of "play" ... Like I will never say I do basketball, but I play basketball. However, I do say I do martial arts. So I guess not strange after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between everyday English and *terminology*. Many fields, for example sports and computing, have their own set of terminology in which certain words may be used differently to how they might be used in everyday speech.

From an English language point of view, I see no problem with "I do BMX". 'BMX' is generally recognised as a shortened form of 'BMX Racing', which in turn is the name of a sport. Especially as this example is in response to the question "do you do any sports?", it seems clear you mean that you participate in the sport called 'BMX'. Although 'BMX' as a term can also refer to the style of bike used, it is recognised as an abbreviation for "bicycle motorcross", the name of the sport in which they are used.

From a sporting terminology point of view, the best people to ask would be people who actually do BMX as a sport to see if "I do BMX" is idiomatic among the sporting community.